# Play Framework Too many open files

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework

We use the Play! Framework 2.3 with Java.
We have a major issue in production which stops our applications from running and sending out data to clients.

We get the dreaded "too many open files" error and have googled, but have no idea how to fix this! It happens every couple of days, here is the error:

```
2016-12-14 02:18:01.098 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-71619] ERROR application - 

 ! @72c9gl98c - Internal server error, for (GET) [/gettodaysfixturesbycompid/886] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:316) [play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46) [play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:430) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:438) ~[spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:261) ~[spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getTodaysFixturesByCompId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.APIController.getTodaysFixturesByCompId(APIController.java:1295) ~[classes/:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$25$$anonfun$apply$231.apply(routes_routing.scala:804) ~[classes/:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$25$$anonfun$apply$231.apply(routes_routing.scala:804) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(Router.scala:264) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:255) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:55) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
 at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:67) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46) [play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:485) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:82) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:252) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121) ~[play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483) ~[play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483) ~[play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519) ~[play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519) ~[play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496) ~[play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496) ~[play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:159) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor87.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor44.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:460) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:520) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:980) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.configureSocket(StandardSocketFactory.java:134) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:205) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

This then caused the database connection link to fail and it just spirals out of control from there.

When I run:

```
lsof | grep <play_java_pid>
```

I get a whole lot of these:

```
java       88655  88792       root  txt   unknown                           /proc/88655/task/88792/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
java       88655  88792       root NOFD                                     /proc/88655/task/88792/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
java       88655  88793       root  cwd   unknown                           /proc/88655/task/88793/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
java       88655  88793       root  rtd   unknown                           /proc/88655/task/88793/root (readlink: Permission denied)
java       88655  88793       root  txt   unknown                           /proc/88655/task/88793/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
java       88655  88793       root NOFD                                     /proc/88655/task/88793/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
java       88655  88794       root  cwd   unknown                           /proc/88655/task/88794/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
java       88655  88794       root  rtd   unknown                           /proc/88655/task/88794/root (readlink: Permission denied)
java       88655  88794       root  txt   unknown                           /proc/88655/task/88794/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
java       88655  88794       root NOFD                                     /proc/88655/task/88794/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
```

Here is the actual API call that is trying to be executed:

```
public Result getTodaysFixturesByCompId(Long compId) throws JSONException, ParseException {
    Logger.debug("Get Todays Fixtures by compId: " + compId);
    List<Object[]> fixtures = fixturesService.getTodaysFixturesByCompId(compId);

    // Loop through fixtures and create JSONObject response
    ArrayList<JSONObject> fixList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fixtures.size(); i++) {

        JSONObject fixture = new JSONObject();
        fixture.put("id", fixtures.get(i)[0]);
        fixture.put("fixture_date", fixtures.get(i)[1]);

        String fixtureDate = "" + fixtures.get(i)[1];
        String fixtureTime = "" + fixtures.get(i)[2];

        Logger.debug("fixtureDateTime: " + fixtureDate + " " + fixtureTime);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
        Date date = sdf.parse(fixtureDate + " " + fixtureTime);

        Logger.debug("Parsed date: " + date);

        Time timeValue = new Time(date.getTime()); 

        fixture.put("fixture_time", timeValue);
        fixture.put("venue", fixtures.get(i)[3]);
        fixture.put("country", fixtures.get(i)[4]);
        fixture.put("team_id_1", fixtures.get(i)[5]);
        fixture.put("team_id_2", fixtures.get(i)[6]);
        fixture.put("competition_id", fixtures.get(i)[7]);
        fixture.put("sheets_processed", fixtures.get(i)[8]);
        fixture.put("team_name_1", fixtures.get(i)[9]);
        fixture.put("team_name_2", fixtures.get(i)[10]);

        fixList.add(fixture);
    }

    setAllowAccessOrigin();

    return play.mvc.Controller.ok(fixList.toString());
}
```

And then my DataConfig class:

```
public class DataConfig {

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("models");
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter); 
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();      
    return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

}
```

The error seems to be on this line in my controller:

```
List<Object[]> fixtures = fixturesService.getTodaysFixturesByCompId(compId);
```

The fixturesService method:

```
public List<Object[]> getTodaysFixturesByCompId(Long compId) {
    String jpql = "select *,(SELECT name FROM teams WHERE id=team_id_1) AS teamname1,(SELECT name FROM teams WHERE id=team_id_2) AS teamname2 from fixtures WHERE (DATE(fixture_date)=DATE(NOW()) AND (competition_id='" + compId + "')) ORDER BY fixture_date,fixture_time";
    javax.persistence.Query query = em.createNativeQuery(jpql);
    List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

Please help?

Comment: You omitted part of the stack trace, the part that identifies where in your code the exception originates.  Please post the COMPLETE stack trace as well as the code.  Offhand I'd say you are leaking database connections somewhere. I.e. you are opening connections repeatedly and not closing them.  Did you at one point have to greatly increase the number of connections supported by the database due to running out?

Comment: Is this your code: `controllers.APIController.getTodaysFixturesByCompId(APIController.java:1295)`?

Comment: Hi, yes it is this line: List<Object[]> fixtures = fixturesService.getTodaysFixturesByCompId(compId);  -- See edit above in question

Comment: OK, NOW you have a possibly-answerable question.  Hopefully someone with the requisite knowledge/experience will see this and help.  It may take awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You leak DB connections. It's not in the code that you describe, try to look where you open connection to the DB and where you close it.

Comment: I am using the Spring EntityManager. Declaring services as a @ Transactional class and the EntityManager as @ PersistenceContext. I don't open and close connections myself.

Comment: I think, it could be the issue with integration Play and this entity manager.

This one could be your case:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2890

Try to refactor your code so it closes the connection explicitly.  Like in the answer to this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683520/do-i-need-to-annotate-jpa-actions-with-transactional-in-play-framework-1-x-to-p (yes, that one about play 1.x, but idea is the same - try to close connection manually)